# Using jQuery-mobile popup as context menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile popups as context menu fired on right click on desktops and taphold on mobile devices.

My problem: when I right click, the popup appears - it works fine. But when the popup is open and i right click outside of popup, the popup is closed and the standard browser context menu appears instead of new popup.

The popup create a new layer (its class is ".ui-popup-screen" ) under itself to catch events, but something like

```
$(".ui-popup-screen").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#myElementWithPopupContextMenu').contextmenu();
    return false;
});
```

does not work.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: do you have some code for us or a jsfidle for the taphold/ricghtclick-solution? thanx!

Comment: Warning to future readers reading this from google: Using jqm popups for context menu's is a bad idea if you plan on having copy / paste functionality.

jqm popups prevent other elements gaining focus, which causes the popular methods of copying to clipboard to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i like to write like follow pattern.

```
// prevent default contextmenu and trigger as 'custom-contextmenu'
$(".ui-popup-screen")
    .bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // create and show menu
        $("#myElementWithPopupContextMenu").trigger( "custom-contextmenu" );
    });

// context menu handler
$("#myElementWithPopupContextMenu").bind( "custom-contextmenu", function(e) {
    // my context menu
}
```

Comment: well, the problem is, that jQuery somehow blocks events on the .ui-popup-screen layer. When I write `$(".ui-popup-screen in").bind("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 alert("something");
 return false;
});` and I click outside of popup, nothing happens

Comment: $("#yourPopupId").on({
    popupbeforeposition: function () {
        $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
    }
});

Comment: Wow, thanks, its exactly what i was looking for. Please write it as another answer, so i can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: do you have some code for us or a jsfidle for the taphold/ricghtclick-solution? thanx!